# Subsequence with odd indices.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

I make one examlpe from the book "Introduction of real analysis" by G. Bartle, R. Sherbert.

We have a sequence $x_1:=1, x_2:=2$ and $(x_n):=\frac{1}{2}(x_{n-2}+x_{n-1})$. So it's not difficult to see, that

$|x_n-x_{n+1}|=\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$ for $n \ \in \ \mathbb N$. To establish the limit we have to consider the subsequnce of $(x_n)$ with odd indices $(x_{2n+1})=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^3}+....+\frac{1}{2^{2n-1}}$.

Can somebody explain me, how did we get this sum on the right-hand side? I have tried to play with $(x_n)$, but I didn't get this sum. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Something's wrong, that formula for $x_{2n-1}$ gives $x_1=3/2$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson yes, you are right, I am sorry. I will edit it. It has to be $x_{2n+1}$

Comment: @GerryMyerson I edited it, can u give me a Tipp now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can establish both $|x_n-x_{n+1}|=\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$ $(*)$ and $x_{2n+1}= 1+\frac12 +\dots+\frac{1}{2^{2n-1}}$ inductively. As you are asking about the latter, I will assume the former.

For $n=1$, $x_n=1$ is an assumption and thus the base case is trivial. Now, assume $x_{2n+1}= 1+\frac12 +\dots+\frac{1}{2^{2n-1}}$. Let us show $x_{2(n+1)+1}=x_{2n+3}= 1+\frac12 +\dots+\frac{1}{2^{2n+1}}$. Use the definition, then $(*)$  to write
$$x_{2n+3}=\frac12(x_{2n+2}+x_{2n+1}) = \frac12(2x_{2n+1}+\frac{1}{2^{2n}}) = x_{2n+1}+\frac{1}{2^{2n+1}},$$
and the induction hypothesis completes the proof.

I expect it is this way you are expected to see the formula. Depending on your level, it could have been nice if they have added "it is easy by induction to see that..." or something similar, making it easier to accept.

Comment: Thank you for the answer) But the question is where did this sum come from ?)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. The formula is true, it follows directly from the assumptions. If you ask how other people have discovered it previously, they probably saw that $x_{n+2}=\frac12(x_{n+1}+x_n) = \frac12(2x_n+\frac{1}{2^n-1}) = x_n+\frac{1}{2^n}$, which is a natural substitution to use, and then saw that you can work with the even and the odd terms separately (i.e. $x_{n+2}$ is determined by $x_n$, which is determined by $x_{n-2}$ and so on). Then they worked out a couple of the terms before the felt they had an idea for the general formula, then proved it as we did.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Yes, you understood right. Hmm, I got that $x_{2n+1}=\frac{1}{2^{2n-1}}+\frac{1}{2^{2n-2}}+....+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^0}$. But it's not the same, what I have at book, because the limit of this sequence is $\frac{5}{3}$ and I got that limit is 2.

Comment: Oh, I got it ) thank you